# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'Test Doubles' complaint even with test project unloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I've been wrestling with this exception for the better part of the day:

```
The member 'Add' has not been implemented on type 'DbSet`1' which inherits 
  from 'DbSet`1'. Test doubles for 'DbSet`1' must provide implementations of
  methods and properties that are used.
```

When I research this specific exception, all results point to modifying the mocks in the unit tests. The funny thing is, I've **unloaded my unit test project** with all the mocking stuff. Research into the overarching `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` returns very broad results, some of which I've tried to no avail. I've pored over the .csproj files, the.soln file, and the web. and app.configs, but nothing jumped out at me as unusual.

Here's my situation:

I'm using ASP.NET MVC as the client to my WCF service, which runs some reporting tool. I'm using Entity Framework Code First to database results of the reporting tools *and* configurations generated by the ASP.NET MVC client. As mentioned, I've unloaded my unit testing project temporarily.

In my controller, I have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ReportConfig reportConfig)
{
   _Context.ReportConfigs.Add(reportConfig);
   _Context.SaveChanges();

   _Client.Run(reportConfig, _Context);

   return RedirectToAction("index", "reportConfigs");
}
```

The exception occurs at the `_Client.Run(reportConfig, _Context);` line, where `_Client` is an instance of the generated ServiceReference client class. The MVC client continues to run if I step past the exception, but the service does not call the `Run(...)` method. I've been using SvcTraceViewer.exe to get more information. Here are the first few lines of the stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.GetInternalSetWithCheck(String memberName)
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
ReadArrayOfReportFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
ReadReportsContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
```

Here's some additional information from SvcTraceViewer:

```
Activity Name   Process action 'http://tempuri.org/IReportService/Run'.
Time    2016-05-18 15:02:30.1716
Level   Error
Source  System.ServiceModel
Process WcfSvcHost
Thread  11
```

I'm keeping it simple for now and only using the Visual Studio Hosting Process. I've cleaned the solution, deleted bin/obj directories, regenerated the Service Reference, turned off lazy loading & proxy generation for my entities... I'm coming right up on my wit's end. If any one has experience this exception under a similar circumstance, what are some steps I can start with to solve this problem?

I'm new to StackOverflow, so if I can improve this question or provide any additional info, please let me know.

Thanks much!

Comment: You're trying to pass an EF context as a parameter to a WCF service call?  I can't imagine that ever working.  Serialization/deserialization is only going to bring over the properties, which is probably why it's complaining about `Add` not being implemented.  I bet it's assuming you are trying to mock when you are not.

Comment: Shoot. Thanks @Paul, that was it.